# Add custom fields to Stripe checkout information and send via webhook

Tags: php, wordpress, stripe-payments

I am using wordpress to build a website that uses Stripe as its payment gateway.

Through the [Paid Membership Pro](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/) plugin I have configured my Stripe connection.

The issue I am faced with is that I need to append a custom field, in this case a unique identifier for the customer, to the payment information for it to be available to send via my webhook to my server for processing.

I have come across a load of answers but none seem to be doing exactly what I am looking for.

I noticed in the PMPro plugin it allows you to add [User Fields](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/documentation/user-fields/create-fields/) which I presumed would be a way to add custom data to the information but after checking the JSON payloads in Stripe none of the user field information is available.

I then tried adding the code from [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346408/pass-custom-checkout-field-value-to-stripe-gateway-in-woocommerce) answer to my functions.php file in word press just using a test meta key but again this information was not available in the payloads.

I am not using woocommerce.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which Stripe event(s) are you expecting these custom fields to be available on? That will determine which parameter you need to use when creating your Checkout Session.

Comment: After some research I believe the metadata fields can contain custom information. My issue is I dont know how to populate them via wordpress.

Comment: Yes, generally you'd use the `metadata` parameter(s) [[1](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-metadata), [2](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata)] to persist custom fields on either the Checkout object or the Payment Intent. Again, which of those parameters you'd use would depend on which event you're listening for. However whether you can control the session creation to pass these parameters would depend on the PMP plugin. I don't have my context about that.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://www.paidmembershipspro.com/gateway/stripe/stripe-checkout/) for PMP, it seems they don't allow users to configure the code that creates the Checkout Session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to crack this using a php script that intercepts the Stripe checkout event.

I added this as a snippet to my Wordpress site and to read in a custom field from the post submit.

Stripe allows you to add custom filed data to the metadata block and once populated this was successfully sent to my webhook.

```
function my_pmpro_stripe_params_send_user_id( $params, $order = null ) {
    global $my_pmpro_checkout_order;
    if ( empty( $params['metadata'] ) ) {
        $params['metadata'] = array();
    }

    if ( empty ( $order ) ) {
        // Save order while creating payment intent.
        $order = $my_pmpro_checkout_order;
    } else {
        // Use saved order while creating subscription.
        $my_pmpro_checkout_order = $order;
    }

    $params['metadata']['my_custom_field'] = $_POST['my_custom_value'];
    return $params;
}
add_filter( 'pmpro_stripe_payment_intent_params', 'my_pmpro_stripe_params_send_user_id', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'pmpro_stripe_create_subscription_array', 'my_pmpro_stripe_params_send_user_id', 10, 1 );
```